# Working out future dates in PHP from days of week and times

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have the following array containing the day of the week (0-6) and time in hrs, mins and seconds:

```
$times = array(     array("1","10:04:00"),
                    array("1","14:20:00"),
                    array("1","20:30:00"),
                    array("1","22:22:00"),
                    array("2","10:14:00"),
                    array("2","14:36:00"),
                    array("2","20:12:00"),
                    array("2","22:42:00"),
                    array("3","12:04:00"),
                    array("3","15:20:00"),
                    array("3","21:30:00"),
                    array("4","23:22:00"),
                    array("4","09:04:00"),
                    array("4","12:20:00"),
                    array("4","19:30:00"),
                    array("4","22:32:00"),
                    array("5","13:04:00"),
                    array("5","16:20:00"),
                    array("5","20:10:00"),
                    array("5","22:02:00")
                    );
```

How can I loop round the above and work out the next date for the event?
For example, if today is Tuesday, the first few dates in the above array would be:

Next Monday at 10:04:00
Next Monday at 14:20:00
Next Monday at 20:30:00
Next Monday at 22:22:00
Today       at 10:14:00
Today       at 14:36:00
etc...

Once the loop gets to the end of the above array, it will loop back to the beginning and so will need to work out the future dates. The dates and times will need to converted to a unix datetime.

Here is the script so far:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("evergreen.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $loopy = 0;
        $thisWeek = date("W");
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if(!isset($times[$loopy])) {$loopy = 0;}
        $dayoftheweek = $times[$loopy][0];
        $thetime      = $times[$loopy][1];
        echo "Day: $dayoftheweek - The time: $thetime<br />";
        // How can I work out the next date and time to post from this?
        $loopy++;
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

I can't work out how to achieve the above. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: just write a function and loop trough the array not that much of a deal.

Comment: Yes, the loop is easy. It is converting the day of the week and the time into a unix date and working whether that will be in the past or in the future. I'll make that clearer in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate dates you can use `strtotime()`. Examples straight from the [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) site:

```
<?php
echo strtotime("now"), "\n";
echo strtotime("10 September 2000"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 day"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds"), "\n";
echo strtotime("next Thursday"), "\n";
echo strtotime("last Monday"), "\n";
```

In your case, you'd put the time in the second parameter:

```
strtotime("+1 day", $timefromloop);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just "ask" [strtotime](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) or [DateTime](http://docs.php.net/datetime)

```
<?php
$weekdays = array(
    '1'=>'monday',
    '2'=>'tuesday',
    '3'=>'wednesday',
    '4'=>'thursday',
    '5'=>'friday'
);
$currentDay = getdate()['wday']; // for php < 5.4 there is no function array de-reference

$times = array(
    array("1","10:04:00"),
    array("1","14:20:00"),
    array("1","20:30:00"),
    array("1","22:22:00"),
    array("2","10:14:00"),
    array("2","14:36:00"),
    array("2","20:12:00"),
    array("2","22:42:00"),
    array("3","12:04:00"),
    array("3","15:20:00"),
    array("3","21:30:00"),
    array("4","23:22:00"),
    array("4","09:04:00"),
    array("4","12:20:00"),
    array("4","19:30:00"),
    array("4","22:32:00"),
    array("5","13:04:00"),
    array("5","16:20:00"),
    array("5","20:10:00"),
    array("5","22:02:00")
);

$times = array_map(function($e) use ($weekdays, $currentDay) {
        $q = $weekdays[ $e[0] ]; // get the name of the weekday for strtotime
        $q.= ' '.$e[1]; // append the time of the event

        if ( $e[0]==$currentDay ) {
            return strtotime($q);
        }
        else {
            // for any other day than today "ask" strtotime for the next/coming day with that name
            return strtotime('next '.$q);
        }
    },
    $times
);


foreach($times as $ts) {
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts), "\r\n";
}
```

prints (today)

```
2015-02-09 10:04:00
2015-02-09 14:20:00
2015-02-09 20:30:00
2015-02-09 22:22:00
2015-02-10 10:14:00
2015-02-10 14:36:00
2015-02-10 20:12:00
2015-02-10 22:42:00
2015-02-11 12:04:00
2015-02-11 15:20:00
2015-02-11 21:30:00
2015-02-12 23:22:00
2015-02-12 09:04:00
2015-02-12 12:20:00
2015-02-12 19:30:00
2015-02-12 22:32:00
2015-02-13 13:04:00
2015-02-13 16:20:00
2015-02-13 20:10:00
2015-02-13 22:02:00
```